# If package package-lock.json is present facing authentication issue

Tags: node.js, node-modules

If I remove the `package-lock.json` during the Jenkins build, will there be any major issues?

If I do not remove the `package-lock.json`, the error I get is

npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, your authentication token appears to be invalid.